# How to use tokens in php code of the rules module?

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I'm using Ajax_comments to add comments on nodes without having to reload the page on save. Now the "node history" doesn't get updated which throws off the "new comment" count.

I tried to create a rule to update the node history on "comment save". Seems like my only option is to execute PHP code. How do I combine PHP code with tokens to get something like this:

```
if ([current-user:uid]) {
   db_merge('history')
     ->key(array(
       'uid' => [current-user:uid],
       'nid' => [comment:node:nid],
     ))
     ->fields(array('timestamp' => [site:current-date]))
     ->execute();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the above code works when I turn of the [Ajax Comments](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module. With that module, it throws an internal server error.

I reported it as [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1543424).

This hook does the job now:

```
function hook_comment_insert($comment) {
  //dpm($comment);

  if ($comment->uid) {
   db_merge('history')
     ->key(array(
       'uid' => $comment->uid,
       'nid' => $comment->nid,
     ))
     ->fields(array('timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME))
     ->execute();
  }
}
```